# Realm.io with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, realm

I m trying to store my retrofit objects in a `Realm.io` db. I've followed the snippet [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#other-libraries) but still having issues. Any help on this would be tremendously appreciated.

My code is

the custom `GSON` parser

```
import com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy;
import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class CustomGsonParser {

    public static Gson returnCustomParser(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();
        return gson;
    }
}
```

the realm call

```
private void requestData(){
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getResources().getString(R.string.app_url))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(CustomGsonParser.returnCustomParser()))
            .build();

    BackendAPI api = adapter.create(BackendAPI.class);

    api.getColleges(new Callback<List<College>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<College> colleges, Response response) {
            mItems = colleges.toArray(new College[colleges.size()]);

            realm.beginTransaction();
            List<College> realmObjects = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(colleges);
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }


        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    });
```

and the object, i left out the setter and getter methods

```
import java.util.List;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.Ignore;

public class College extends RealmObject{
    private String name;
    private String shortName;
    private String mainColor;
    private String secondaryColor;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;
    private int id;
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `realm.beginTransaction();

List<College> realmObjects = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(colleges);

realm.commitTransaction()`


crashes with, what I believe to be, a stack overflow error

Comment: That is an error you will get if Gson isn't configured correctly, but from your code it looks like you are using a correct configured Gson instance.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I tested on device and it worked, created a new emulator based on api 22 and it worked.